# Differences between VSCode and SublimeText 4 HTML+JavaScript syntax highlighting

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, serverside-javascript, sublimetext4

Can someone explain to me why Sublime Text 4 highlights this HTML differently than VSCode?

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            if (true) { 
        </script>
        
        <script>
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both have `HTML` as the selected syntax.  I'm also using the same textmate color-scheme in both.

**Sublime Text 4**

[image: ST4 HTML+JS]

(inspected with the [Scope Hunter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) package)

**VSCode**

[image: VSCODE HTML+JS]

(inspected with Developer tools in VSCode)

[image: VSCode dev tools]

**UPDATE**

I am working with a server-side JavaScript platform where breaking the blocks up like this is a thing like PHP.

**UPDATE 2**

I am working on a syntax highlighter, but not for server-side JS.

Comment: Because `if (true) {` makes no sense?

Comment: @Andy you can put whatever in there.

Comment: It doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: @Andy I think I'm missing something implied in your comments.  Maybe you could give a nod to the community and chime in with an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The real question is, why should they properly highlight it in the first place? You can't split up `<script>` blocks. You can do something similar in PHP, though, but your question is about JavaScript.

You can create a simple `test.html` document with your HTML and open it in a browser. Opening developer tools (e.g. in Chrome) will show errors about "unfinished scripts" and such.

Comment: I'm working with a server-side JS platform, so it does behave like PHP in that way.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs — Are you using syntax highlighters designed for *that* server-side JS platform? Or syntax highlighters designed for HTML with embedded client-side JS?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs then the server-side JS should be in some sort of template tag, like `<?php ... ?>` for PHP for `<% ... %>` for any number of templating languages. Splitting up `<script>` tags is illegal.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs If you're using something like EJS, there should indeed be a certain tag to begin/end server-side JS blocks. I'm not sure VS Code or Sublime would have support for those, although there might be extensions that do.

Comment: All valid points. I don't think a grammar exists for this particular flavor of SSJS.

Comment: So ST4 is playing fast and loose and VSCode is more strict?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs that seems to be the case, yes. ST4 strictly checks for the `</script>` end tag while VS Code tries to handle it in a smart way. To be fair, with JSX/Babel/... your JS code can actually have XML/HTML-like tags as code, and it's technically not doing anything wrong due to the "illegal" (well, unexpected) JS splitting.